# How to get a Date from a string of UNIX epoch ms in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

As the title says. I found some questions on how to do the opposite, but how to get a Date when I have a numeric string of miliseconds in the UNIX epoch?

Comment: `new Date(value)`, see [*EMCA-262 §20.3.2.2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value), also [*MDN Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use directly from JavaScript the following function (no dojo is required)

`new Date(value)`

For example, if you pass a value in milliseconds like:

`new Date(1463033875207)`

you get a date object.

Below an example of the result of a built–in toString :

```
Thu May 12 2016 08:17:55 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

You can read more bout this object here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: A Date object doesn't have any format at all, it's just a time value with a few handy methods (and lacking a few really handy others). The above string is the result of calling the built–in *toString* method, which is entirely implementation dependent and can be whatever the implementation's developers decided to use. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks fore your comment, I made an edit to my question to be more accurate.